# Yeoman generator overwriting Gruntfile.js variables

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have made a Yeoman Generator and am copying a folder with Grunt config inside. But the generator's variables are the same and thus Grunt is processing then and they are removed.

In the Yeoman Generator I begin the copy with:

```
    this.directory('grunt', 'grunt');
```

In a file in the grunt folder above is something like:

```
    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
```

Which I want to stay in the file, but the Yeoman generator is processing this and all I get is a blank string.

Is there a way to disable variable processing when copying directories in a Yeoman generator?

Answer (score 0):

The variables were being overwritten because I was using the key `config` which seems to be reserved by the Yeoman Generator.

Once I changed the variable name in the Gruntfile to `settings` (or anything else) then the Yeoman Generator would leave it alone and it would come into my Gruntfile correctly.